# How to get measurements once I clicked on "Done" button?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I need to get measured values once I clicked on "Done" button, like you can see here:

[image]

With other words - when user clicked on "Done" button, I need to "catch" all measured values. How to do that, please?

Thank you

Comment: Anybody, please?

Comment: Is there any other place where I can ask for help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get all measurements currently, there is no function could be used to get all measurements shown on the screen as I know, although you can call `measureExtension.measureTool.getCurrentMeasurementRaw()` to obtain last created and selected measurement.

In addition, all measurements stored in the measure extension will be deleted while clicking the `Done` with my research, and the returning value of `measureTool.getCurrentMeasurementRaw()` will be set to null, too. Therefore, it's hard to achieve what you want so far. Sorry for the bad news.